# How to convert CLLocationDegree from any other data type in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, ipad

I have implemented google map in iOS.I want to get the CLLocationDegree for longitude & latitude from NSString.

**code used to get the NSString from Json**

```
 lat=[latLong objectForKey:@"lat"];
 lng=[latLong objectForKey:@"lng"];
```

**Solution i tried**

```
 latitude=[lat doubleValue];
```

But this does not working.

Please tell how can i convert `NSString` into `CLLocationDegree`?

Comment: Can you print out "lat" value?

Comment: your coding is correct , check once **lat** contains value or not

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution i was declaring wrong

**Use** `CLLocationDegrees longitude;`

**instead of** `CLLocationDegrees *longitude;`